# Performance: single loop with multiple statements or multiple loops with single call

Tags: javascript, performance

Targeting Javascript, which of these should be fast?

Multiple loops with single statement:

```
var array = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 500000; i++) {
    a1();
}
for(var i = 0; i < 500000; i++) {
    a2();
}
for(var i = 0; i < 500000; i++) {
    a3();
}
```

or Single loop with multiple statements:

```
var array = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 500000; i++) {
    a1();
    a2();
    a3();
}
```

To try to understand it I ran it on jsperf.com. Check it out here: https://jsperf.com/loops-or-calls/1. But, theoretically, which should have best perfomance? **and why?**

**Edit 1:** I don't why, but running it on reverse order change the ops/sec:
Multiple statements has poor perfomance than multiple loops. https://jsperf.com/loops-or-calls/1

**Edit 2:** I don't think it has any difference because: 5k times x 3 ops = 15k. Otherwise: 5k (first loop) + 5k (second loop) + 5k (third loop) = same 15k;

Comment: single loop....

Comment: Those aren't multiple calls. They're a call and a couple of operations.

Comment: why my question is being underrated?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry my mistake, now i put arbitrary functions being called, to abstract the statement and focus on the loop issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## My Answer

Multiple statement in single for loop with counter being incremented is fastest

## Logical Explanation

## For Multiple Loops:

So consider this, you are running loop multiple times for different calls/statement. You would probably think, it shouldn't matter if you put it in single for loop as number of operation being performed are same. if you think same, you are wrong! lets break it down:

#### First Loop

- First time first loop runs, it initializes counter `i = 0`  and reads checks if `i<500000` then calls the function or runs the expression then increases counter `i++`

  - **Number of operations:** 4
- Rest `499999` times it checks if `i < 500000` and then calls function or runs the expression and increments the counter by 1 each time.

  - **Total Number of Operation in `499999` cycles:** `3 operation each time x499999 = 1499997`
- Final time it checks if `i < 500000` it returns false and breaks the loop.

  - **Number of operations:** 1

#### Total Number Of Operation For First Loop:

4 + 1499997 + 1 = 1500002

#### Other Loops

- Second loop and other loops follows same procedure, and in this case has same number steps.
  **Total Number Of Operations for three loops:**
  1500002 x 3 = 4500006

  ## For single loop with, Multiple Statements/Calls:
- First time loop runs, it initializes counter `i = 0`  and reads checks if `i<500000` then runs the expressions or calls the functions in our case its 3 function for first array member then increases counter `i++`

  - **Number of operations:** 6 operations
- rest 499,999 time, it checks the condition, and runs expression or calls function and increases the counter

  - **Number of operation:** 5 operation per cycle = 5 x 499999 = 2499995 operation
- Final time it checks if `i < 500000` it returns false and breaks the loop.

  - **Number of operations:** 1

**Total Number Of Operations for single loops:** 6 + 2499995 + 1 = 2500002

## Difference in number of operations carried out internally

> **4500006 - 2500002 = 2000004**
>     2000004 operations more!!!!!

## Why is decrementing loop slow!

- First time loop runs, it initializes counter `i = 500000`  and reads checks if `i>-1`, Now before function runs it first populates array an empty array with 500,000 member, and then calls the function or runs the expressions in our case its 3 function for first array member then increases counter `i--`
  so internally it runs 499999 operations to create empty member and then at index 500000 calls the function or runs the expression.

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I doubt there is a significant logically explainable difference in javascript, but lets say it is C++ or something like that. The single loop would be faster in typical case, but the reason is more hidden. The impact of three loop values is small, because:

- incrementing is fast
- condition that is false 99,999% of the time is fast (can be predicted)
- loop can be unrolled

The biggest problem with three loop is, that the whole array has to be read through three times and if it does not fit into cache, You have cache misses. Three loops have worse data locality and therefore are slower.

On the other hand it depends what the a1(), a2(), a3() are. If those operations are so big that they compete for cache memory on some internal data structures, the three loops may outperform the single loop. But it would not be the typical case.

Answer (score 1):

Single loop is definally better, because when you arrive there you just do 3 things in a loop and then you do the rest. In the first case you have to loop on a single instruction 500000 times then 500000 times on the next one and so on.

Comment: If it is possible obviusly use the second option

Comment: I don't think it has any difference because: 5k times x 3 ops = 15k. Otherwise: 5k (first loop) + 5k (second loop) + 5k (third loop) = same 15k;

Comment: @Richard The loop itself has (at least) two operations: one that increments the counter and another that checks the condition. That's 20k more operations if you have three separate loops.

Comment: key comment. thank you!

Comment: @Richard as @JJJ said there is the `i++` and the `if` that are implemented in the `for`. Those are more operations.

Answer (score 1):

Single loop will be faster.

The operations inside ( `a1`, `a2`,  `a3`) will be performed same number of times in both options, but there's the additional cost of increasing the counter `i` and checking whether it had reached the limit.

When you make 3 loops this is done 500000*3=1.5M times, with a single loop it's done only 500000 times.